# Docker.Dotnet UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing docker engine from inside a container using named pipes

Tags: .net, docker, blazor, windows-server-2019, windows-container

I have created an ASP.NET Blazor server app that queries the Docker engine using the [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) library. I build the app as a Docker Windows container image and map the named pipe '\.\pipe\docker_engine' when running the container. Everything works fine on my Win10 dev machine with docker desktop. I can access the containerized Blazor app and get a list of containers from the host.

Now, when I try to run this image on a Windows Server 2019 VM I get an exception (from the Blazor app inside the container):

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
 at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.TryConnect(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 ...
```

If I deploy and run the Blazor app directly on the server, it works fine.
I also run [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) on the server and it works fine.

Do I need to configure something special in the Docker.DotNet code to get it to work from inside the container?

This is the Docker.DotNet code:

```
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration().CreateClient();
IList<ContainerListResponse> containers = await client.Containers.ListContainersAsync(
    new ContainersListParameters()
    {
        Limit = 100,
    });
```

and this is how I start the container:

```
docker run -dt --restart=always -p 80:80 -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production" --name DockerBlazor -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine dockerblazor:latest
```

Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
In the Dockerfile I needed to add

```
USER ContainerAdministrator
```

and now it is working.